# How do I get wget output in ruby?

Tags: ruby, stdout, wget

I need to run the following code from ruby:

```
system "wget http://example.org/some/large/archive.zip"
```

When I run this command I see

> Redirecting output to ‘wget-log’.

I need to do `tail -f wget-log` to see the progress

How can I see wget output in terminal where I run the ruby process?

I've tried

```
system "wget -O - http://example.org/some/large/archive.zip > dev/null"
```

but it didn't help

Maybe there are other options to download large archives with ruby and see the progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) module, which is in the Ruby's standard library.

This *grants you access to stdout, stderr, exit codes and a thread to wait for the child process when running another program*.

So, having a `pwd` command you can do something like:

```
require 'open3'
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3('pwd')
puts stdout # ~/ current directory
puts stderr #    no error
puts status # pid 25522 exit 0
```

Comment: `Open3.capture3` didn't work with wget for me. It worked with `Open3.capture2('wget http://example.org/some/large/archive.zip')`

Comment: Yes, slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby provide a good built-in libs to make any kind of http things, for example to download file you can use `net/http`:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI(URI.encode("http://example.org/some/large/archive.zip"))
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host,uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.path

  http.request request do |response|
    open "/tmp/my_large_file.zip", 'w' do |io|
       response.read_body do |chunk|
         puts "Writing  #{chunk.length} bits ..." # see progress
         io.write chunk
       end
     end
  end  
end
```

With `wget` *you unable* to catch any kind of http errors in your ruby code.*

With `wget` *you unable* to make auth, basic for example in your ruby code.*

Use Ruby built-in libs, it is very powerfull.

<sub>You able but with some buggy code</sub>